# rails cancan roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am using devise for my authentication system and cancan for permissions. I am in the process of adding roles and I am trying to have it so when a user signs up he will automatically be assigned a role. I watched [ryan bate screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) and also followed a [devise & cancan tutorial](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) .

How I can implement this without using check boxes and automatically assign a role to user based upon when they're signing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a callback: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

The `before_create` callback is probably what you want in your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_default_roles
  private
    def set_default_roles
      self.roles = ['Default user']
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`AR::Callbacks` does the trick for you, however I prefer setting up roles when User object is firstly initialised:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_default_roles

  private
    def set_default_roles
      self.roles = self.roles || [Role.find_by_name('Default Role')]
    end
end
```